# Show current date in tree view header

Tags: xml, python-2.7, odoo-10

How to show current date in the header part in tree view near import button in odoo 10?

For example:- I want to add current in header of tree view(near import button).

So, what will be the solution?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Would you please share your efforts in your question.

Comment: I have tried javascript code in web module in base.xml file in static/scr/xml/base.xml:-                                                                                       <p id="date"></p>
<script>
document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = Date();
</script>                                                                                                     it works but it is for all modules and all views. So how can we use it in custom modules. I have tried implementing this in custom module but it does not work. May i get some solution for this?

Comment: For your js code give this to any particular class which is defined by you in your view. So by this way this code only affect to particular class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create One xml file with below xml template.

**above_xml.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<templates id="template" xml:space="preserve">
        <t t-name="ImportView.import_button">
            <button t-if='widget.options.import_enabled' type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default o_button_import">
                Import
            </button><t t-if="widget.model =='sale.order'">&amp;nbsp;<div id="curr_date_on_top" class="btn btn-sm btn-default oe_inline"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var today = new Date();
                document.getElementById('curr_date_on_top').innerHTML = today.getDate() +"/"+(today.getMonth()+1)+"/"+today.getFullYear();
            </script>
            </t>
        </t>
</templates>
```

Then add it in the manifest file in qweb section.

```
   ....
   qweb:['/static/src/xml/above_xml.xml']
   ....
```

That's it.

Comment: Hello, I tried the above code but it didn't work, the whole view get disappeared. Is there any modification in the above code?

Comment: it is spell mistake at the closing tag of templates.. my bad.
check now. i updated that.

Comment: how can i implement it in a particular custom module recently it is for all module? Is there any solution?

Comment: You mean it implemented for all model's listview you want only for any perticular model's listview?

Comment: I edited my answer. now, only implemented for sale.order so, you can change it to your custom model.